# MonoTouch integrate facebook cancel button invisble

Tags: facebook, xamarin.ios, cancel-button

I am developing an iOS app with MonoTouch, i have integrated Facebook sdk in this app, but the cancel button on the facebook screen is invisible. 
I saw this solution here [Facebook cancel button is invisble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991852/facebook-cancel-button-is-invisble)

but i don't know what FBDialog.bundle means in monotouch terms, anybody has ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [facebook bindings from github](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/facebook) and built it yourself.

> i don't know what FBDialog.bundle means in monotouch terms

A `.bundle` is a directory. It can contains resources, like bitmaps.

When you build the bindings, the [sources](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) of the Facebook SDK will be downloaded, from github, including the [FBDialog.bundle](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/src/FBDialog.bundle) which includes the [bitmaps](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/src/FBDialog.bundle/images) you're looking for.

What you need is to tell MonoDevelop to include this `.bundle` with your application. See the [blog entry](http://conceptdev.blogspot.ca/2009/08/monotouch-settingsbundle.html) from Craig Dunn to learn how to add a bundle. Once added to your application the SDK will be able to find (and use) the bitmaps it requires.